# DIY op-amp power supply

Tags: operational-amplifier, power, amplifier, negative-voltage, vcc

I purchased a DIY op-amp kit from eBay. The parts arrived in a baggy, I soldered it all together, but have no idea how to wire the power supply?

I am hoping to use 9V batteries, and realize I might have to run two or more in series? I am pretty new to this electronics thing.

What is confusing me is that the hookup has "VDD", "-GRD-", and "-VCC". I have no idea what connects to what in terms of batteries, etc.

I have attached several photos with the amp, chips, etc. It did not come with instructions, datasheets, etc.

[image: Circuit Board]

[image: Power Hookup]

[image: Chip]

Comment: Thank you for all the photos, but it would help a lot more if we could look at the schematic.

Comment: I don't have one. It came in a baggy, no instructions, no datasheets, nothing. Sorry.

Comment: We need a **schematic** to be able to say anything useful about this circuit. You have the PCB so you can **reverse engineer** the schematic from that. Did you look on the website printed on the PCB? **Probably** you need a symmetrical supply like + 9 V and - 9V. **Probably** the module will work of you apply + 9V to VDD and - 9 V to VCC but anyone why marks supplies like that has no clue, this doesn't follow normal conventions (VDD and VCC are both for positive voltages, VSS and VEE are for negative rails).

Comment: In that case I suggest you trace the connections and reverse engineer the board. Otherwise it is not much use to you and you will not understand how it works and you will not learn anything from it either.

Comment: You could try: VDD + (9V battery) - GND - + (9 V battery) - VCC  But **no guarantees** if this is wrong your opamp might be damaged. Only a schematic will tell me if what I propose is OK or not. Next time: buy a kit **with a schematic**. For an experienced EEs this is easy, we just measure where the supply pins of the NE5532 go. But for a beginner, you need a schematic.

Comment: I tried the website but it is all in chinese. Doubt I have the experience to "reverse engineer" anything at his point. Wouldn't even know where to start?

Comment: Just check out what are the op-amp power pins and see which terminals they go?

Comment: The negative lead should be connected to the negative side of the LED.  The LED positive side is marked.  You can also look at the orientation of the electrolytic capacitors next to the power connector.  They are connected to the ground plane - middle power connector.

Answer (score 4):

> I am hoping to use 9V batteries, and realize I might have to run two or more in series?

This is how to make bipolar power supply using two batteries.

[image]

And for reverse engineering the board - check to which connector terminals goes pin4 and pin8 of the IC. Then connect batteries correspondingly +Vs to Vcc+, -Vs to Vcc- and GND to GND.

[image]

Image taken from [Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne5532.pdf).